# dynamic dispatch performance for generics

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic, dynamic-dispatch

I have more than 30 classes that are used as generic parameter for a class `Child`. here `TKind` can be any class from set of about 30 classes.

```
internal sealed class Child<TKind> : Base
{
    public override void SupplyTo(IBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.AddPart((dynamic)this);
    }
}
```

The builder has `AddPart` overload for all 30 cases that we can have.

This will not compile :

```
 builder.AddPart(this);
```

because `this` is a generic type and compiler cant resolve method overload. because it doesn't know if overload is provided for this generic type or not.

but this will compile since we are using dynamic dispatch and method overload is resolved at runtime.

```
builder.AddPart((dynamic)this);
```

I'm worrying about performance. `AddPart` overloads may be called thousands times. does compiler optimize `dynamic` part after it resolves overload for the first time for each generic type? does it know that `this` will be always the same type in that context?

will only first call for each generic type be an expensive call and rest of the calls will be like directly calling a method overload?

Lets give an example. **first approach** :

```
 foreach(Base item in items)
 {
     builder.AddPart((dynamic)item); // dynamic dispatch
 }
```

I assume here compiler can not optimize dynamic call because `item` can be anything.

**second approach**:

```
 foreach(Base item in items)
 {
     item.SupplyTo(builder); // double dispatch
 }
```

but in the above example we are using visitor pattern, and in each generic class, `this` is always same type. so there should be some optimizations in second approach?

Comment: It's really hard to answer, because we don't know what kind of performance you're expecting. Let's say that the runtime does some optimizations so that subsequent calls are faster than the first call. It still doesn't give any information on whether the subsequent calls are fast enough for your needs (as they're likely still slower than a raw method call). On the other hand, if no optimization is done, maybe it's still fast enough for your needs. Long story short: measure first, then decide if any optimization is needed

Comment: 30 overloads for AddPart is the bit that has me puzzled. Can't AddPart just take a base class? That's the whole point of OOP. What does AddPart do that requires it to have all those overloads for derived types?

Comment: 30 overloads is used because we have separate algorithms that is written for each `TKind`, so we cant share algorithm using one overload. (the other way would be simply switch on type, but I found double dispatch looks cleaner.) @AdamBenson

Comment: But wouldn't you have a base class with a virtual DoStuff() method in it that gets overriden in each of your derived types? Or am I missing something :-)

Comment: Builder class has a lot of fields, each time AddPart is called one of these fields is modified, some of them log errors in some cases, I cant have `DoStuff` for each `TKind` because these fields should be managed within builder. @AdamBenson

Comment: Hmmm ... OK. You're the man on the front line in this case, but I'd honestly suggest you may have things the wrong way around here. If these fields belong to derived classes then I would ask whether or not Builder has to know about them or whether the logic that deals with those particular fields could be moved into your specialized classes. Typically, in a factory pattern, you do indeed have one class that knows about all possible types - but only so that it can create them, that's it. It doesn't usually have any other specialized knowledge. But, like I said, you're the man in the trenches.